# How to prevent StackOverflowException when reusing a callback in a callback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, recursion

I have some code that relies on the HttpContext.Cache, where I want it to re-cache something if a certain criteria is met. However, this introduces a potential stack overflow, and I'm not sure what would be the appropriate approach here.

Look at this code snippet:

```
void OnCacheItemRemoved( string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason )
    {
        var c = value as RequestCounter;
        if ( c == null )
            return;

        if ( .. Some logic that might be true .. )
        {
            Cache.Insert( key, c, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds( timeWindow ),
                Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Low, OnCacheItemRemoved );
        }
    }
```

When debugging this, the stack trace doesn't seem to build up, but in real life scenario, it does. Could this depend on how the callback is invoked (like, if the cache would be released instantly for some reason)?

Also, what would be the best solution around this? Pass in a delegate with duplicated code (maybe move the logic except the Cache.Insert to a common method)? I'm still afraid that it would built up a stack anyway, and I'm not sure what options I have.

Any advice?

Comment: I hope the problem then doesn't become that, even without a StackOverflowException, you could have an infinite loop OnCacheItemRemoved->Add, removed because full, OnCacheItemRemoved->Add

Comment: Can you log the `CacheItemRemovedReason reason`?

Comment: Are you concerned about the callback stack building?

Comment: @xanatos Good point, I haven't been able to replicate it in my dev env, but logging the reason is a good start.

Comment: @TravisJ well, not only concerned, it's a fact that it throws a StackOverflowException in production. I just don't know why this isn't traceable in my dev environment.

Comment: @jishi - I guess what I was trying to ask was if the overflow was from memory or from the call stack.

Comment: @TravisJ Well, it's unlikely that it would be because of memory, since it's a 64-bit process and it has over 100GB of free RAM, unless there is another restriction that I'm unaware of. And wouldn't that throw an OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: @jishi - Okay, just making sure :) In my opinion, you should consider caching the recursive calls in that case to remove duplication (if there is any).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73264/discussion-between-jishi-and-travis-j).

Comment: @jishi - Why don't you come to the [c# chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c) instead of that one

Comment: Is it possible that timeWindow = 0? This could cause your remove callback to be called within Cache.Insert- over and over

Comment: @wheatin No not in this case. Either way, I'm curious to in which scenario the callback would create a recursive stack, because when testing it (when the callback is triggered by an expire) I don't see a repeat of OnCacheItemRemoved in my stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an answer with my observations:

One solution to prevent a StackOverflowException in this case

```
    void OnCacheItemRemoved( string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason )
    {

        if ( reason != CacheItemRemovedReason.Expired )
        {
            return;
        }
```

At least, this prevents the stack from overflowing. The theory behind the cause of the stackoverflow exception seems to be that the callback is called, when the cache item is replaced (or re-cached by the insert). Two parallel requests, that would try and cache the same item, would create a race-condition where the first cached item, would be expired by the second request thus invoking the callback which in turn would insert it again, invoking the second callback and resulting in an infinite invalidation with reason "Removed". It seems like that race would build up the call stack, where as when the expiration thread does not.